# jQuery Select2 not closing anywhere (also not on their own website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have built this select2 ajax dropdown and after finishing it i figured it didn't close after opening. Looking for a solution I came across the official website (select2.org) and also here the dropdowns won't close after opening.

This is my code:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

```
    $('#prescriber_id').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: 'prescribers/dropdown_search',
            delay: 250, // wait 250 milliseconds before triggering the request,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
                var query = {
                    search: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1
                }

                // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
                return query;
            }
        }
    });
```

Also i tried adding "closeOnSelect: false". But that didn't change a thing.
Anything else works fine.

Does anyone know what's going on? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue as the default select2 will close once you have selected an option - see their demo page: http://select2.github.io/select2/#basics

Comment: any error is showing in console ? 
And Is it multiple select box or single select box ?

Comment: @pete Can you try the dropdown over here:
https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax
This one gives me the problem (this seems to be select2 v4.0.6). Youre example is v3.5.3.
Maybe i should just use that older version.

Comment: @RonakChauhan There are No errors in my console, its a single select box.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? could be a known issue: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5485

Comment: @Pete I'm using jquery 2.1.1 but the problems remains with v3.4.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug occurring on single select boxes with version 4.0.6. It is fixed in 4.0.7-rc.0